# Как конвертировать Long EpochDays в LocalDate?

Tags: java, localdate

Для расчётов мне требовалось перевести LocalDate в epochDays, теперь надо обратно. Пока сделал вот такую конструкцию:

```
private static final Long DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 86400000L;

LocalDate actualDAte = Instant.ofEpochMilli((date * DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS) - DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Не самый лучший вариант, мне кажется, к тому же, он выдаёт неправильные данные. Есть ли другой способ перевести дни в дату?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так можно, без лишних кастомных телодвижений, в которых можно накосячить лишний раз:

```
Instant.EPOCH.plus(epochDay, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .toLocalDate();
```

---

```
    LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println(d);
    long epochDay = d.toEpochDay();
    d = Instant.EPOCH.plus(epochDay, ChronoUnit.DAYS).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();;
    System.out.println(d);
```

> 2018-04-10
>
> 2018-04-10